# Send form to url and save generated document on my server

Tags: php, forms, curl

happy new year to all.
I was asked to create a tool to send some info into a website and save a PDF generated with that info.

Is that possible?

I've coded a few scripts to send info into a form, but never heard of the downloading part.
Is it doable? what should i use or where do i start reading?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is doable...Though not that easy..There are libraries which provide such support..

[Read and use this](http://www.fpdf.org/)

And to Download files curl provides functionality to download and save a file from a remote server to your server read this post they have given a demo of the same..
[Read this to Download and Save files](http://phpsense.com/2007/php-curl-functions/)

Comment: Which are? i am absolutely new to this. Thanks

Comment: I've given you link to one..:)

Comment: Sorry, that creates a PDF file, what i need is this: i send some information into external url, external url processes that info and generates a downloadable PDF with that info, what i need is to get that PDF and save it into my server.

Comment: Awesome library..so easy to use..download it and follow the tutorial..So easy to generate pdf from php code..

Comment: How are you sending it to the external url, directly from the client form??

Comment: I think curl itself provides functionality to download and save a file from a remote server to your server read this post they have given a demo of the same..http://phpsense.com/2007/php-curl-functions/